# How do i fix the "Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" error?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I haven't used spring or any java in a few months now. And I am trying to create a simple Spring project similar to a previous one I did.
However, I am getting the following error at the very start of the project creation, when I run the application.
Its strange because my other project runs fine. Any help at all is appreciated.

Thanks

## 1 Error

```
   Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

   Property: driver-class-name
   Value: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
   Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
   Reason: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig 
   class 
   loader or Thread context classloader

   Action:

   Update your application's configuration
```

## 2 POM

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
   4 
  4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.goodLife</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>





    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <layout>ZIP</layout>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>

 </project>
```

## 3 Application Properties

```
server.port=8080

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.dataSourceClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:3306/goodlife? 
useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&autoReconnect=true
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

Comment: Your dependency on `mysql-connector-java` should have made `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` available but Maven may have corrupted it when it downloaded its jar file. Try clearing it from Maven's cache and running your application again.

Answer (score 0):

So the following link explains my issue and the resolution : https://blog.csdn.net/qq_38261445/article/details/91899747

Explanation :  "First of all, this is a project in springboot. It roughly means that a certain driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver is not loaded. You are reporting this error because you cannot find the corresponding driver to connect to the database. Package, so the only configuration that can be involved in the springboot project is application.properties and application.yml files; of"